# Why is the background color not changing?

Tags: jquery, html, css, background-color, oracle-apex

I've got a problem to highlight some rows in a table generated by apex.

With dynamic actions and jQuery, I was able to highlight single columns

jQuery:

```
$('tr td[headers="IDZ"]').each(function(){
  if(parseInt($(this).html()) == 12){
    $(this).attr('style','background-color:red');
  }
});
```

Result in html:

```
<td align="right" headers="IDZ" style="background-color:red">12</td>
```

Works fine, the column where IDZ == 12 is red now.

But I want to highlight the entire row so I thought let's get the parent node `<tr>` and add some "style".

jQuery:

```
$('tr td[headers="IDZ"]').each(function(){
  if(parseInt($(this).html()) == 12){
    $(this).parent().attr('style','background-color:red');
  }
});
```

and the result:

```
<tr class="even" style="background-color:red">
```

Row didn't change their background color and I have no idea why. Tested with Firefox and Chrome.

I'm grateful for any hints or solutions.

Mario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting a background for a <tr> doesn't always work reliably, you are better to set it for all the child <td> or <th>s.

A good way to do this would be to replace your

```
$(this).parent().attr('style','background-color:red');
```

with

```
$(this).parent().addClass('highlightit');
```

then add css

```
tr.highlightit td { background-color: red; }
```

that will make all the table data elements under that table row have a red background.

Comment: Thanks. I got it. Instead a class i use an id, because apex generated tables have '<tr class="even"....> <tr class="odd"...> <tr class="even"....>' and so on.

Comment: You can add multiple classes to elements, it would just come out as <tr class="even highlightit">. An id should only be used as an identifier and there should only ever be one instance of an id on each page for reliable results.

Comment: ah ok. but with class="even[odd] highlightit" the highlighting doesn't work.

Comment: I've been styling the backgrounds of trs for years and never seen any problems.

Answer (score 2):

Try this JS code instead ([**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pBMjc/)). Worked for me

```
$('tr td[headers="IDZ"]').each(function(){
  if(parseInt($(this).html()) == 12){
    $(this).parent().css('background-color','red');
  }
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `.closest('tr')` and I've used `text` instead of `html`

```
$('tr td[headers="IDZ"]').each(function(){
    if(parseInt($(this).text()) == 12){
        $(this).closest('tr').attr('style','background-color:red');
    }
});​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dUgTz/3/).